# How to create MSI installer

Tags: python, windows-installer, customtkinter

I am a beginner at creating MSI, so I don't know much about it. Here, I need to create an installer. When the user clicks the installer exe file, it should automatically install and set up Python and PostgreSQL on their system. When setting up PostgreSQL, it should also create the user role and password. How can I achieve that using this?

I am attempting to implement this functionality using a Tkinter application. However, I encounter an issue during package installation where the Tkinter window becomes unresponsive due to the User Account Control (UAC) prompt. It becomes stuck at that point.

### Python installing code:

```
`python_url = "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.0/python-3.10.0-amd64.exe"
 ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
 ssl_context.check_hostname = False
 ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
 installer_path = "python-3.10.0-amd64.exe"
 with urllib.request.urlopen(python_url, context=ssl_context) as response, open(installer_path, 'wb') as installer_file:
       installer_file.write(response.read())
       process = subprocess.run([installer_path, '/quiet', 'InstallAllUsers=1', 'PrependPath=1'])`
```

### PostgreSQL code:

```
download_url = "https://sbp.enterprisedb.com/getfile.jsp?fileid=1258893"
 download_path = "postgresql-installer.exe"
 response = requests.get(download_url, stream=True)
                with open(download_path, 'wb') as file:
                    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                        if chunk:
                            file.write(chunk)
if os.path.exists(download_path):
                    install_command = ['runas', '/user:Administrator', download_path, "/SILENT", "/COMPONENTS=postgis"]
install_process = subprocess.run(install_command, capture_output=True, text=True)`
```

- When executing Python code, a User Account Control (UAC) prompt appears. It is not directly visible as it runs in the background; during this time, the Tkinter window becomes unresponsive.
- While executing the SQL code, I encountered an error

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1921, in **call**
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 839, in callit
func(*args)
File "C:\Users\cybrosys\Music\cyllo_installer.py", line 588, in execute_commands
self.execute_command(cmd, admin_passd, flag_value, value)
File "C:\Users\cybrosys\Music\cyllo_installer.py", line 709, in execute_command
install_process = subprocess.run(install_command, capture_output=True, text=True)
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 501, in run
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in **init**
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 740] The requested operation requires elevation

Comment: Nothing like pyinstaller? Or you actually need Python itself installed?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Wix Toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/)?